# How to save the messages in pdf format

Tags: reactjs

I have array of data called `chatMessages = [{message: 'hi hello ', dest: 'left'},{message: 'hi hello op', dest: 'left'}`

I'm trying to save the messages in pdf format but only first message is saving in pdf `hi hello`
what i'm doing wrong here please help me thanks in advance

```
const saveCallingInfo = () => {
const [dataMessages] = (chatMessages !== undefined ? chatMessages.map(item=> [item.message]) : "");
  var doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.text(10,15,'list of conversation');
    doc.autoTable({
      theme: 'grid',
      startY: 20,
      head: [['Messages']],
      body:[[dataMessages]],
    });
    doc.save('Info.pdf');
 };
```

Comment: are you using jspdf package to create pdf? Did you tried consoling the `[dataMessages]` array?

Comment: yes i'm using jspdf package. the console.log is showing  only single message `[hi hello ]`